# Why does this take so long to compile in VCC 2003?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

My team need the "Sobol quasi-random number generator" - a common RNG which is famous for good quality results and speed of operation. I found [what looks like a simple C implementation on the web](http://people.scs.fsu.edu/~burkardt/cpp_src/sobol/sobol_old.C). At home I was able to compile it almost instantaneously using my Linux GCC compiler.

The following day I tried it at work: If I compile in Visual Studio in debug mode it takes about 1 minute. If I were to compile it in release mode **it takes about 40 minutes.**

Why?

I know that "release" mode triggers some compiler optimization... but how on earth could a file this small take so long to optimize? It's mostly comments and static-data. There's hardly anything worth optimizing.

None of these PCs are particularly slow, and in any case I know that the compile time is consistent across a range of Windows computers. I've also heard that newer versions of Visual Studio have a faster compile time, however for now we are stuck with Visual Studio.Net 2003. Compiling on GCC (the one bundled with Ubuntu 8.04) always takes microseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I'm not really sure the codes that good. It's got a nasty smell in it. Namely, this function:

```
unsigned int i4_xor ( unsigned int i, unsigned int j )

//****************************************************************************80
//
//  Purpose:
//
//    I4_XOR calculates the exclusive OR of two integers.
//
//  Modified:
//
//    16 February 2005
//
//  Author:
//
//   John Burkardt
//
//  Parameters:
//
//    Input, unsigned int I, J, two values whose exclusive OR is needed.
//
//    Output, unsigned int I4_XOR, the exclusive OR of I and J.
//
{
  unsigned int i2;
  unsigned int j2;
  unsigned int k;
  unsigned int l;

  k = 0;
  l = 1;

  while ( i != 0 || j != 0 )
  {
    i2 = i / 2;
    j2 = j / 2;

    if ( 
      ( ( i == 2 * i2 ) && ( j != 2 * j2 ) ) ||
      ( ( i != 2 * i2 ) && ( j == 2 * j2 ) ) )
    {
      k = k + l;
    }

    i = i2;
    j = j2;
    l = 2 * l;
  }

  return k;
}
```

There's an i8_xor too. And a couple of abs functions.

I think a post to the [DailyWTF](http://www.thedailywtf.com/) is in order.

EDIT: For the non-c programmers, here's a quick guide to what the above does:

```
function xor i:unsigned, j:unsigned
  answer = 0
  bit_position = 1
  while i <> 0 or j <> 0
    if least significant bit of i <> least significant bit of j
      answer = answer + bit_position 
    end if
    bit_position = bit_position * 2
    i = i / 2
    j = j / 2
  end while
  return answer
end function
```

To determine if the least significant bit is set or cleared, the following is used:

```
bit set if i <> (i / 2) * 2
bit clear if i == (i / 2) * 2
```

What makes the code extra WTFy is that C defines an XOR operator, namely '^'. So, instead of:

```
result = i4_xor (a, b);
```

you can have:

```
result = a ^ b; // no function call at all!
```

The original programmer really should have know about the xor operator. But even if they didn't (and granted, it's another obfuscated C symbol), their implementation of an XOR function is unbelievably poor.

Comment: I'm primarily a python developer so this looks like nonsense to me... other than the general unreadability of this code what is actually wrong with it?

Comment: The comments say that this code was ported from Fortran 77. Does Fortran 77 have an XOR operator?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using VC++ 2003 and it compiled instantly in both debug/release modes.

**Edit:**

Do you have the latest service pack installed on your systems?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you download a trial edition of Visual Studio 2008 and try the compile there, just to see if the problem is inherent. Also, if it *does* happen on a current version, you would be able to report the problem, and Microsoft might fix it.

On the other hand, there is **no** chance that Microsoft will fix whatever bug is in VS2003.